# using components and modules from another projects angular5

Tags: module, angular5

I am working on 2 different angular cli(angular5) projects and project1 is almost done and just starting project2. I was wondering if it is possible to use some of components and services can be share to project2 from project1? Can this be done in a simple way so I don't need to publish but taking care internally without coppying files. I don't want to grab a whole projects but only those necessary components and services.(Not sure how I can handle if the name of the service is the same like translateService)?

Comment: when u say `I don't need to publish` ... do you mean to publish as an `npm publish` installer

Comment: yes I don't want to make my stuff publicly available

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want to create a local package and reuse it other projects by doing something `npm` commands, I would suggest you to use [ng-packagr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-packagr).

It's setup is pretty straightforward. You can find tutorials such as [this on over medium.](https://medium.com/@nikolasleblanc/building-an-angular-4-component-library-with-the-angular-cli-and-ng-packagr-53b2ade0701e)

I have been using it for quiet sometime in our project to reuse some of the services etc and we have named that project as `client-infrastructure`.

Let me know if you need more clarification on this.

Answer (score 0):

As it can only be achieve if you architect the project in correct way means distribute your `Presentation` and `Container Component`  in proper way.
Here is a best article that can understand help you to understand the process

https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2018/11/how-build-reusable-angular-components-share-world/